# How to set up transparency node with factor controlling the Alpha

Tags: node-editor, transparency

I'm have a node set up on the first example, with a mix shader which controls the opacity from 0-100 for the Cube shape, And on the second example I also have Fresnel, and RGB curves which plug into the mix shader node, and I lose the ability to control the Alpha. What node do I need to add to have the ability to control the factor on the second node set up?

[image]

Comment: You could put a (Converter) Math node in Multiply mode?

Comment: Hi MB

I added the multiple mode (Math Node) I can control the Alpha value, but the cube looks flat. Is this the node set up you were suggesting?

https://ibb.co/zsTDCf8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add transparency, create a second *Mix Shader* and play with its *Factor*:

[image]

Comment: That worked better, Merci!